# "unrecognized selector sent to instance" when selector is in other file

Tags: ios, swift

Here is the problematic ViewController class.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    
    @IBOutlet weak var photoSelectActionSheet: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var selectedImageView: UIImageView!
    
    var imagePicker: UIImagePickerController!
    var selectedImage: UIImage? = ni
    
    var iCloud = ICloud() // see below for code of that file
  
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        
        // Must use this system to check each time the view appears.
        // This is checked each time so if user goes into settings and come back in same session
        // then this will be updated => viewDidLoad is cached and not reloaded each time.
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
            self,
            selector:#selector(ICloud.checkIfUserIsLoggedInIcloud), // PROBLEM IS HERE
            name: UIApplication.didBecomeActiveNotification,
            object: nil)
    }

    // more code not shown

}
```

Problem is in viewWillAppear: the notification center calls a selector that is in an other Model file ICloud.swift:

```
import UIKit
import CloudKit



class ICloud {
    
    
    var isLoggedInIcloud: Bool? = nil
    var userIcloudId: String? = nil
    
    
    func getUserIcloudId() {
        // Run this only if user is logged into icloud, and we don't have yet its iCloud id.
        if isLoggedInIcloud ?? false && userIcloudId == nil {
            CKContainer.default().fetchUserRecordID(completionHandler: { (recordId, error) in
                if let id = recordId?.recordName {
                    print("userIcloudId set to: " + id)
                    self.userIcloudId = id
                }
                else if let error = error {
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                }
            })
            
        }
        
        
    }
    
    @objc func checkIfUserIsLoggedInIcloud() {
        // Check if user is logged into iCloud
        CKContainer.default().accountStatus { accountStatus, error in
            if accountStatus == .available {
                self.isLoggedInIcloud = true
                print("isLoggedInIcloud set to true")
                
                self.getUserIcloudId()
                
                return
            }
            
            print("User is not logged into icloud")
        }
    }
    
}
```

I expected "ICloud.checkIfUserIsLoggedInIcloud" passed in selector to work. It doesn't:

> 2020-07-01 11:46:12.931419+0200 QDog[53348:3422745] -[QDog.ViewController checkIfUserIsLoggedInIcloud]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fcad5f0c1d0
> 2020-07-01 11:46:12.938567+0200 QDog[53348:3422745] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception

If I add back the functions and variables from ICloud.swift directly into the ViewController file and pass to the selector "checkIfUserIsLoggedInIcloud" it WILL WORK properly.

I wanted to put all icloud code into a separate model file for separation of concerns and to make the code more clear.

Question is: why does 'ICloud.checkIfUserIsLoggedInIcloud' passed as selector doesn't work? And how to make this work with ICloud code in its own file, and not in ViewController file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsnotificationcenter/1415360-addobserver), the first parameter should be the observer, which in your case you're pointing to `self`.

In this case, `self` is your ViewController, which doesn't have the method `checkIfUserIsLoggedInIcloud`. In order to make it work, as an observer, you need to pass the property `iCloud` instead of `self`.